# Forma de recoger el nombre de usuario del directorio activo en ASP .NET C#

Tags: c#, .net, webforms

Estoy intentando estas dos formas de recoger el nombre del usuario que entra a la página web desde el directorio activo pero la segunda forma no funciona.

Sí funciona:

```
System.Security.Principal.IIdentity identity = null;
identity = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
identity.Name.ToString() ---> dominio\\nombreUsuario
```

No funciona:

```
System.Security.Principal.IIdentity identity = null;
identity = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
identity.Name.ToString() ---> siempre es null
```

Quería saber porque la segunda forma no funciona, gracias!

Comment: Yo uso `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`, sin el system

Comment: Sí, vale, ese ahora sí me funciona igual que la primera forma que he puesto arriba. También creo que ha sido que he habilitado la autenticación windows en el proyecto y he desactivado la autenticación anónima.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solución:**

Usar `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` sin el `System` y
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28041831/19682608